# Java ActionListener code not generating "toggling" functional via JButton

Tags: java, jbutton, actionlistener

button b1 is a button with no text and, initially, a black background.  When clicked upon, b1's ActionListener switches its background to an icon.  When clicked upon again (or any number of times), b1 simply stays as this icon, whereas my desired functionality is to have it switch back to a black background.  Toggling, via mouse clicking, between a black background and this icon, is my goal.  But it simply stays put as this icon.  The code snippets necessary for resolving the error are posted below.  I would be grateful for any insight.  IDE = Eclipse.  Box = Mac Retina.

```
 ...some code...

 JButton b1 = new JButton();

 ...some code...

 b1.setOpaque(true);
 b1.setBorderPainted(false);
 b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

 ...some code...

 icon = new ImageIcon[12]; //Behind the scenes here is that the source is randomly assigning
 icon[0] = alpha;          //images via an array.  This is not significant, but done for continuity.

 ...some code...

 b1.addActionListener(                                     //Anonymous Listener Class
        new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              if(b1.getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK)) {
                 b1.setIcon(icon[0]);
                 b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
              }
              else {
                 b1.setIcon(null);
                 b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
              }               
           }});
```

Comment: I realize the code above is not best practice, but I'm more interested in figuring out why these statements in particular do not produce the desired toggling functionality as opposed to coming up with a syntactically different answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the original code I posted was compilable, runnable and achieved the desired result.  My Eclipse IDE was running by default a previous version of dysfunctional code, which is a bug.  I take responsibility for my user error and I am grateful for the alternate answers that people generated, which taught me a lot.  In the end, I simply submitted the code I originally posted for my assignmnet because it is representative of my level of understanding of Java at this present time.

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on the `getBackground()` method of the `JButton` to know if it was clicked or not, for example `java.awt.Component.setBackground` could be called on another component that would change the background of the button.

```
public void setBackground(Color c) {
    Color oldColor = background;
    ComponentPeer peer = this.peer;
    background = c;
    if (peer != null) {
        c = getBackground();
        if (c != null) {
            peer.setBackground(c);
        }
    }
    // This is a bound property, so report the change to
    // any registered listeners.  (Cheap if there are none.)
    firePropertyChange("background", oldColor, c);
}
```

So I would do something like:

```
b1.addActionListener(                                     //Anonymous Listener Class
        new ActionListener() {
           private isBlack = true;
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

              if(isBlack) {
                 b1.setIcon(icon[0]);
                 b1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
              }else {
                 b1.setIcon(null);
                 b1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
              }
              isBlack = !isBlack;
           }});
```

Comment: Why?  Do you dispute that the statement

     if(b1.getBackground().equals(Color.BLACK))

is using Object's equals method to return a boolean value based upon the comparison of b1's background and the constant BLACK?  And do you dispute that this supposed boolean statement is enclosed in an IF statement, within which only a boolean statement may be placed?  Your code may work, but you provide no answer as to why mine does not...

Comment: Actually, when I saw the implementation of `Component.setBackground`: `Component
public void setBackground(Color c) {
Color oldColor = background;
ComponentPeer peer = this.peer;
background = c;
if (peer != null) {
c = getBackground();
if (c != null) {
 peer.setBackground(c);
}
}
// This is a bound property, so report the change to
// any registered listeners.  (Cheap if there are none.)
firePropertyChange("background", oldColor, c);
}`
I saw that setBackground could have side effect, so maybe some part of your code is changing the button Background. Using the boolean would be saffer.

Comment: @DigitalImpermanence it's a good OOP design rule to separate visual UI states from domain logic as far as possible - relying on visual UI state in making logic choices is both a code smell and possible bug nest - avoid that at all costs. My answer would be exactly the same as Xavier's, regardless of the actual reason for your problems with this code.

Comment: @Xavier Delamotte     I have no idea what your talking about, but in any case, your code elicits a change to the button only after a second click and not upon a first.  My code elicits a change after the first click, but produces no toggling functionality.

Comment: @vaxquis   Okay, but see my response to Xavier above.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I made a mistake on the initialisation of the boolean. Corrected.

Comment: @Xavier   Was the mistake that isBlack was initially initialized as false?  And you've now edited that to true?

Comment: @Xavier   The code works and I thank you for the correction but I'm still confused as to why my code did not work in the first place.  It's important I get this fundamentally answered because every time some GUI assignment comes up I end up losing points because my Listener code doesn't work.  Despite the smell of my original code, it should be possible to produce the desired toggling functionality using the general idea I have above.  I'm more interested in finishing this question off with my code because then I will at least SPECIFICALLY understand where I've been going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the code smell coming from using Components `getBackground()` as a state indicator, the code sample you provided above is **correct**. You can easily try out this [SSCCE](http://sscce.org):

```
package swingtest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingTest {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws MalformedURLException {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame( "SwingTest" );
        JButton jb = new JButton( "test button" );
        jb.setOpaque( true );
        jb.setBorderPainted( false );
        jb.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
        URL url = new URL( "https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/images/oracle-java-logo.png" );
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(url);

        jb.addActionListener( //Anonymous Listener Class
                new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed( java.awt.event.ActionEvent e ) {
                        if ( jb.getBackground().equals( Color.BLACK ) ) {
                            jb.setIcon( imageIcon );
                            jb.setBackground( Color.WHITE );
                        } else {
                            jb.setIcon( null );
                            jb.setBackground( Color.BLACK );
                        }
                    }
                } );
        jf.add( jb );
        jf.setSize( 800, 600 );
        jf.setVisible( true );
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    }

}
```

It works as intended, try it out yourself. Your problem is thus unrelated to the code you provided. Xavier's right, either something else is screwing with the colors/icons set (another button maybe?), or you have a heisenbug, unrelated to JButton & ActionListener at all.